# Unity infinite background change with transition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have the infinite background set up with the tiling method which is moving from the right to the left, what i want to do is that if the player reaches an amount of score(like 1000), i want to change the background via a transition, like the next background will move in from the left to the right like the other one did, but when it moves in, it stays till the player reaches another amount of score(like 2000). Then it happens again but now with an other texture.

The current script looks like this:

```
public class BackgroundScroll : MonoBehaviour {

Material material;
public Material materialChange;
Vector2 offset;

public int xVelocity, yVelocity;
private float backgroundSpeed = 1f;
public static float speed = 10f;
private float speedUp = 0.1f;
private int changed = 0;

private void Awake()
{
    material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    speedUp = 0.1f;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    changed = 0;
    //offset = new Vector2(xVelocity, yVelocity);
    StartCoroutine(Speed());
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    offset = new Vector2(xVelocity, yVelocity);
    material.mainTextureOffset += offset * Time.deltaTime * backgroundSpeed;
    BackgroundChange();
}

void BackgroundChange()
{
    if (ScoreHandler.score >= 100 && changed == 0) 
    {
        material.mainTexture = materialChange.mainTexture;
        changed = 1;
    }
}

IEnumerator Speed()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(20);
    speed += speedUp;
    backgroundSpeed += speedUp;
    }
}
```

This line changes the background, but there is no animation or transition at all, it just changes it: `material.mainTexture = materialChange.mainTexture;`

So my question is that how can i change the background with an animation, so it slides it then it stays till the other one slides in and that stays. etc...

Comment: `but when it moves in it stays till the player reaches an another amount of score(like 2000).` please add the complete code for both solutions you tried. I can imagine how the rest of your first solution looks like but please add it. In general: use Coroutines for something like that ([StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html))

Comment: Edited, i also made it to one script instead of two.